# List has no rows for assignment to SObject - interesting context

Tags: wrapper-class

I am trying to solve my problem with a wrapper I've previously had - I couldn't have a lookup in a wrapper because some metadata is missing. To overcome that I am trying to add sobject to my wrapper and then access that lookup field (supplier__c).

The trouble is that subquery has no results, because further down my logic I actually I want to mass insert new tariffs__c.

Is there a way around this?

I hope the question is clear enough.

```
    contract__c[] tariffsTrapped = [select id,meter__r.name, 
                                     (select id, supplier__c from tariffs__r) 
                                     from contract__c where id in: selectedmeters];
    for(contract__c met: tariffsTrapped){
        tariffsWrapped.add( 
            New tariffsWrapper(
                met.id,
                met.tariffs__r,
                met.meter__r.name
            ));
    }
```

Comment: Is SelectedMeters empty? Is the Id for the correct sObject type?

Comment: Where you are getting `List has no rows for assignment to SObject `? I don't see anything strange.

Comment: n.b. a better design for your `tariffsWrapper` would be to have the constructor just accept the `met` argument (a `Contract__c`) - that way, if you decide later that the wrapper needs more fields from the Contract (or related lists), the signature of the constructor need not change.  You can use getters or methods inside your wrapper class to expose values to users of the wrapper

Comment: I'm getting the error on runtime on VF page. I believe it is this subquery '(select id, supplier__c from tariffs__r)', as otherwise in my debug log I see 1 result. @crop, that is an interesting idea I have not considered. Will look into it.

Comment: post the excerpt from your VF page

Comment: `<apex:pageblockTable value="{!wrapperObj}" var="Rec">
                <apex:column headerValue="Meter Number" value="{!Rec.uniqueIdentifier}"/>           
               <apex:column headerValue="Supplier"  >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Rec.tariffTrapped.supplier__c}" styleClass="supplier" required="false" id="Supplier"/>
                </apex:column>`

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted my problem with:

```
 for(contract__c met: tariffsTrapped){
        tariffsWrapped.add( 
            New tariffsWrapper(
                met.id,
                new tariff__c(),
                met.meter__r.name
            ));
    }
```